# Bootstrap event not caught in ajax loaded form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to grab the bootstrap panel shown event.  I believe the panel is working, because changing the panels swap the active class on the panels.  However, the event grab is not working.

Here is part of the form:

```
<h4>Discounts</h4>
<ul id="discountTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#brandDiscounts" data-toggle="tab">Brand</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#genericDiscounts" data-toggle="tab">Discount level</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="brandDiscounts">
        <!-- Brand input -->
        <select class="form-control" name="brandID">
            <option value="0">Select a brand</option>

            @foreach($brands as $brand)
                <option value="{{$brand->getId()}}">{{$brand->getName()}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="genericDiscounts">
        <!-- Brand input -->
        <select class="form-control" name="genericDiscount" disabled>
            <option value="0">Select a discount</option>

            @foreach(ProductBase::getDiscountLevels() as $discountLabel => $discount)
                <option value="{{$discount}}">{{$discountLabel}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateDiscountInputs();

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
        updateDiscountInputs();
    });
});

/**
 * Only the active table input should not be disabled.
 */
function updateDiscountInputs(){
    var brandDiscount   = $('#brandDiscounts').hasClass('active');
    var genericDiscount = !brandDiscount;

    $('#brandDiscounts').find('select').prop('disabled', !brandDiscount)    ;
    $('#genericDiscounts').find('select').prop('disabled', !genericDiscount);
}
```

The page that loads first has a select box and making a selection loads (via ajax) in a form that includes the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tabs link are missing some important tags such `aria-control` and `role`

```
<ul id="discountTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#brandDiscounts" aria-control="brandDiscounts" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Brand</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#genericDiscounts" aria-control="genericDiscounts" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Discount level</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also you have to add your event listener after the html is added into the DOM. So you have to add the event listeners in your `$(element).load()` callback function.

For instance:

```
$(element).load(url, function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
        console.log("test")
        updateDiscountInputs();
    });
});
```

Comment: I made your suggested changes and it appears to be doing the same thing.  It isn't catching any of the tab events.  I am using $(element).load(url, function()) instead of .ajax

Comment: Are you adding the event listeners in the load() callback function? see my edited answer

Comment: Yeah, the .load portion of your edited answer is exactly what I have.

Comment: I did that as well.  Also, when I mentioned none of the other events are being caught, I was implying that I also have the same .on() binding for the show, hide, and hidden events.  They each have their own console.log('event name') inside.  None of those appear in the console when changing the tabs.

Comment: there is something wrong with your boostrap library. Everything is working correctly in my tests. Are you using bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 4

Comment: 3.  I've already mentioned that I think that the events are occurring, but for some reason my catches are not.  I put jQuery('body').bind("show.bs.tab", function(e){console.log(e);}); in the console and each time I change a tab, it outputs the console.log(e).

Comment: you will have to try to reproduce your problem in a jsfiddle because everything is working fine in my local tests

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to accept this answer.  The only thing that wasn't working for me was the event binding.  I did get it to work by putting $(document).on('shown.bs.tab', function(){
                updateDiscountInputs();
            }); on the document.ready of the main page.